# Implementing zeta functions of algebraic varieties in SAGE

Tags: nt.number-theory, zeta-functions, sage

I am fairly new to sage, I was studying zeta functions of hypersurfaces over finite fields and I don't know how to compute them in Sage. Are there any packages that do most of the work, or maybe some similar work that I could have a look at to get any ideas?

Comment: Smooth projective hypersurfaces?

Comment: Jan Tuitman used to have good code for hypersurfaces, but it never made it into sage for some strange reason.

Comment: @WillSawin smooth projective hypersurfaces are indeed part of the things that I am trying to implement, specifically the zeta function in its rational form.

Comment: @MartinOrtiz The advantage in that case is that you know a priori the degree of the factors in the zeta function (as well as all terms but one), so if your plan is to calculate the coefficients, you only need to do a controlled number of coefficients (in fact, half the dimension of the primitive cohomology group, rounded up) to get the whole rational function.

Answer (score 1):

Sage has a method `zeta_series()` for arbitrary varieties over finite fields, but it will only give you the first few terms of the power series, not the rational-function closed form; the latter is only available for elliptic and hyperelliptic curves if I remember correctly. Perhaps Singular or Macaulay2 (which are more specifically geometry-oriented) might have more relevant functionality.

Comment: Searching for documentation, I found [this](http://doc.sagemath.org/pdf/en/reference/schemes/schemes.pdf). Relevant section on page 13. It looks like you're referring to zeta_function(), which does return the rational-function closed form. It says it gives the zeta function of a "generic scheme". However the example given returns "NotImplementedError". I imagine the power series from zeta_series() would be useful for finding the rational function if you know its shape (degrees in numerator and denominator, etc.).